# Network connection does not get disconnected on pressing the disconnect button

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking

Most of times,  it happens that I connect my computer to broadband and then i am unable to disconnect it through connection wizard in windows 7. probably this is happening due to some fault in my router as i have been able to replicate this issue on two computers (both win 7).

Even though I press "disconnect" button several times but this doesn't work. Even though I remove the cable it still shows connected. Then I am  forced to restart and then it is disconnected by default. 
So I need a way to forcefully disconnect the connection without restarting my computer each time. is there any way i can do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose why your not getting a disconnection, is the real question, Did you check for your "open connections" to see if that is why windows does not want to stop it?  MSes usual safety stuff to keep from having broken packets, and stopping writes mid stream.

I have always believed that a wire cutter is a good firewall :-)

I have been using DEVCON (device connection) to flat out disable the device itself. 
I put my script that I use in this question [Wired and wireless connections: make Windows prefer Ethernet when connecting to a specific other computer in the network?](https://superuser.com/questions/341815/wired-and-wireless-conections-force-windows-to-connect-to-laptop-through-ethern/341876#comment374177_341876)

With this method, it is almost as good as the wire cutter, It will take some time to get it figured out on your system, then one shortcut button can turn it on and off at will.

It can disable the net device itself completely, you can test the same thing in device manager manually, without it.  Open up the device manager and disable the network device,  and see if "disabling the network device" would do what you want.  The scripting just does the same thing.