# How do I create a hotkey to disable a certain network adapter in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, networking, hotkeys, adapter

I want to make a hotkey which I could use to disable a specific network adapter. Is that possible?  If so, how would I configure that?

Comment: Do you just need the hotkey :-) or the method by which you can disable a network adapter.  http://superuser.com/a/341835/98855 I use "devcon" to disable devices , then put batches with shortcuts. It has never failed.  It is not easy to ID the device at first, but it would be easy to give it a global hotkey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a shortcut to cmd.exe on the desktop and append a specific [netsh](http://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html) command to disable the adapter. Assign a hotkey and you're done

1. Create a shortcut on the desktop and paste

   ```
    cmd /c netsh interface set interface name="interfacename" admin=disabled
   ```
2. Replace *interfacename* with your own adapter name e.g *Local Area Network*
3. Open the shortcut properties and enable *Run as administrator* under advanced. Due to this you will get an UAC prompt everytime. Unfortunately that's necessary or else we get:

   > An interface with this name is not registered with the router.
4. Also in the properties, assign a shortcut key. Remember, these hotkeys only work for shortcuts which are placed on the desktop as [Microsoft states](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/134552)

   [image]